# Cannot show ProgressDialog from AsyncTask : Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have a situation where user taps a particular button and a dialog themed activity is displayed in my app. Since the contents of the second activity (dialog activity) are fetched using an `HttpRequest` I want the user to see a `ProgressDialog` untill the dialog is loaded.

AsyncTask seems the best thing to be used for this purpose. Hence I have written the following class.

```
public class DetailsList extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

public static final String LOG_TAG = "DetailsList";
private Context context;
private ProgressDialog dialog;
private Activity activity;

public DetailsList(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public DetailsList(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this.context);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if(dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String...params) {
    this.publishProgress(100);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "doInBackground started.");
    JSONObject requestContent = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject detailViewResponse = new JSONObject();
    try {
        requestContent.put("serviceId", params[0]);
        APIRequest detailViewAPI = new APIRequest(
                "http://" + GeneralConstants.SERVER_ADDRESS + "/services/",
                requestContent
                );
        detailViewResponse = detailViewAPI.request();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return detailViewResponse.toString();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    dialog.show();
}
```

}

And when the get call is made I have the following exception stack trace :

```
12-29 05:12:29.149: W/System.err(3459): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
12-29 05:12:29.159: W/System.err(3459):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
12-29 05:12:29.159: W/System.err(3459):     at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:112)
12-29 05:12:29.159: W/System.err(3459):     at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:114)
12-29 05:12:29.159: W/System.err(3459):     at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:98)
12-29 05:12:29.164: W/System.err(3459):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:77)
12-29 05:12:29.164: W/System.err(3459):     at threads.DetailsList.<init>(DetailsList.java:30)
12-29 05:12:29.164: W/System.err(3459):     at app.command.DetailViewDisplayCommand.execute(DetailViewDisplayCommand.java:54)
12-29 05:12:29.164: W/System.err(3459):     at commands.Command.execute(Command.java:32)
12-29 05:12:29.164: W/System.err(3459):     at gl.ObjectPicker.findObjectForValue(ObjectPicker.java:92)
12-29 05:12:29.164: W/System.err(3459):     at gl.ObjectPicker.pickObject(ObjectPicker.java:58)
12-29 05:12:29.164: W/System.err(3459):     at gl.GL1Renderer.onDrawFrame(GL1Renderer.java:111)
12-29 05:12:29.164: W/System.err(3459):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1520)
12-29 05:12:29.164: W/System.err(3459):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1244)
```

It seems that the error is triggered from the line where I initialize the dialog.

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(this.context);
```

Comment: try placing this line, `dialog = new ...` inside the classes constructor after `this.context = context;` instead of in `onPreExecute`

Comment: @A--C how did you fix the log ? what formatting was used ?

Comment: @mahesmohan Oddly, this time it hasn't been fixed that well, but if you highlight text then click the curly braces, it makes into a code block. SO is *usually* good at figuring out which formatting to apply next.

Comment: @La I had tried that. Still the same error.

Comment: @A--C Thanks. Would keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3):

```
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1244)
```

An AsyncTask is designed to keep the main Thread from being slowed down by arduous operations. However you aren't on the main Thread, you are on an OpenGL Thread. I haven't tried this myself, but what happens with:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    Looper.prepare();
    Looper.loop();
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this.context);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if(dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    Looper.quit();
}
```

(This may work or it may throw an trying to access the UI from the wrong thread exception.)

Comment: Since the exception is happening in the constructor, I doubt that your mods to `onPreExecute()` will help. But +1 for catching the `GLThread`, as I'd've missed that.

Comment: @Sam Looper did work. There was no exception but still the AsyncTask does not get executed. Also no exception is thrown.

Comment: Placing the prepare and loop methods in the right place can solve the issue regarding the GLThread. But still no ProgressDialog.

Comment: @mahesmohan Try calling `dialog.show()` inside `onPreExecute()`, but if the task finishes immediately you will not see the ProgressDialog.